# How would i get a process pid which is running in a bash script and know when its done

Tags: bash, process, spinner, pid

I need to know an another process pid which is  executed as a command in the bash script like a nmap scan etc as an when the process is created I can display a bar or a spinner 

     `#!/bin/sh
     G='\033[0;32m'
    B='\033[0m'
    ${G}Enter IP TAIL      LIKE 0.1 OR 1.1${B}"
    read v
  ${G}ENTER Device NAME ${B}"
   read k
nmap -A -Pn -sV 192.168.$v   -oN  /tmp/op 
//here i want a while loop for displaying a spinner`

edit code is updated [Thts the code in case tht was not visible properly ^^](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XDejN.png)
As the pid dies when its completed  I can use it as a count or a flag or something similar  to end the spinner.
I'm working on Kali nethunter.

P.S This is my first time on stack overflow pls forgive me if its too stupid or tell me if I missed something.

Comment: Instead of linking to an offsite image of your code, paste the code in here, makes it much easier to read, critique, and help wtih.

Comment: I added the code

Comment: `${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}` what is going on there?

Comment: Referred  this http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/034

Comment: I would also recommend ensuring that the code you've written so far works as far as the problem goes. I don't have `Echo`, `Read`, or `Nmap` commands on my system, so either you are doing something funky, or you haven't put in the minimum amount of work and you really mean `echo`, `read`, and `nmap`.

Comment: This is not even Bash syntax.

Comment: Tht was just an ex of what I wanted actual code is a bit big so sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter IP:"
read -r ip

# `&` runs in parallel
# always quote variables
nmap "$ip" &  
# `$!` get's the background process PID
pid=$!

...

# you can see if a pid is running by checking exit status of `kill -0`
while kill -0 "$pid" 2>&1 >/dev/null; do
    printf ...
    ...
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nmap -A -Pn -sV 192.168.0.1 -p -oN  /tmp/op   >/dev/null & pid=$!
i=1
sp="/-\|"
echo -n ' '
while kill -0 "$pid" 2>&1 >/dev/null;
do
printf "\b${sp:i++%${#sp}:1}"
done
```

***Problem solved thanks to *** kamil cuk